# raphael.js crop image

Tags: image, svg, raphael, crop

I am newbie to raphael.js and svg. I have an image element, i can select rectangles on it using drag and drop in any area. The problem is that image must be transparent, but selected rectangles not.

If i used css i would set background-image for rectangles and background position, but i have not found such possibility for svg (and probably vml for ie).

How can i crop the image and put it over transparent image or set background position to rectangle?

**UPD**: Actually i found the solution: for each newly created rectangle I can copy image and use clip-rect attribute. But this solution does not match my needs. I can not rotate clip-rect area, image only.

Answer (score 0):

The rectangular clip-rect that raphaël provides is a subset of what you can do in svg.

Here's an example of rotated clipping: [masking-path-02-b](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/profiles/1.1F2/test/harness/htmlObjectApproved/masking-path-02-b.html)

Here's something a bit more advanced: [masking-path-07-b](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/profiles/1.1F2/test/harness/htmlObjectApproved/masking-path-07-b.html)